# Getting the 'model' out of Earth

Tags: r

Sorry for the lousy title. Not sure how I should phrase it.

I'm playing around with the Earth package to see about regressing a neural network signal using more or less standard indicators. The data file is 1000's of rows and currently 187 columns (186 indicator results) with my target variable in the last column. The code I wrote is very simple, and leaves out any in-sample vs out-of-sample issues for now, but at least it seems to function:

```
library(earth)
MyData = read.csv("C:\\Users\\TSIT\\\\GS-Pass12.csv",header=TRUE)
x=data.frame(MyData[,1:ncol(MyData)-1])
y=MyData[,ncol(MyData)]

a = earth(x,y,nprune=5)
summary(a, digits = 2, style = "pmax")
```

and the output of summary looks pretty reasonable:

```
summary(a, digits = 2, style = "pmax")
Call: earth(x=x, y=y, nprune=5)

y =  1.2
  - 31 * pmax(0, Percent.Difference.from.Moving.Average..C..10. -   0.096)    
  + 10 * pmax(0, 0.096 - Percent.Difference.from.Moving.Average..C..10.)    
  + 25 * pmax(0, Percent.Difference.from.Moving.Average..C..15. -  0.14) 
  - 16 * pmax(0,  0.14 - Percent.Difference.from.Moving.Average..C..15.) 

Selected 5 of 116 terms, and 2 of 185 predictors  Importance:
Percent.Difference.from.Moving.Average..C..15.,
Value.Oscillator..C..8..26..1.-unused, ... Number of terms at each
degree of interaction: 1 4 (additive model) GCV 0.083    RSS 239   
GRSq 0.66    RSq 0.66
```

The thing I'm struggling with now is how to get the resulting model (y) out of a and into some sort of R variables so that I can use it. Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The model is *in* `a`. How do you want to "use" it? The **earth** package comes with a lot of good documentation - have you read the vignettes?

Comment: Read? Yes. Understood? Likely not very well. I'm not really a programmer and know very little about R. I just struggle along using it when I think there's something I can do in it. Thanks

Comment: You still don't tell me what you want to do with the model? The 5 terms in the model are shown in the summary output. Do you understand what a MARS model is and how the basis function are derived? If yes, then we need to know what you want to do with the model. If you want to **predict** from it, for example, then you can use the `predict()` method. Dirk's Answer took you literally and showed you how to extract a textual representation of the model. I suspect that is not what you want. But if you don;t tell us what you want, specifically, how can we help you?

Comment: I want to get the model into a format where I can use it to make explicit numerical calculations within R. I want to see the output of each basis function and how each part contributes to the total output 'y'. I can code the style="bf" model by hand but I'm hopeful that there's a way to extract both the basis function choices and coefficients automatically. I would then add multiple columns to a dataframe that had each component and the summation of them creating 'y'. Long term, if the model works well enough, it will be rewritten in another language and used outside of R.

Comment: Thanks. I think some of this is covered in the help for `?format.earth` and `?predict.earth`. I would use the latter & `type = "terms"` with prediction data covering the range of each covariate whilst holding the others at their sample means (i.e. partial responses) to visualise the basis functions and provide a decomposition of the contribution to `y`. The `?format.earth` help shows one way to convert output from that function to an R functions. **earth** also has some pretty good plotting capabilities. As you only have a single covariate this is all so much easier.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to ?format.earth. The as.func part of that looks like it might be helpful.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I just encountered it myself..

Comment: Not really. Dirk & Gavin's responses gave me most of the info I needed but I started moving away from R and more to MatLab not long after this thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `format()` function can be used:

```
R> library(earth)
R> example(earth)
[... stuff omitted ...]
R> cat(format(a), "\n")
  27.2459
  +  6.17669 * h(Girth-14)
  -  3.26623 * h(14-Girth)
  + 0.491207 * h(Height-72)
R>
```

There are also alternative formats:

```
R> cat(format(a, style="pmax"), "\n")
  27.2459
  +  6.17669 * pmax(0,  Girth -     14) 
  -  3.26623 * pmax(0,     14 -  Girth) 
  + 0.491207 * pmax(0, Height -     72) 

R> cat(format(a, style="bf"), "\n")
  27.2459
  +  6.17669 * bf1
  -  3.26623 * bf2
  + 0.491207 * bf3

   bf1  h(Girth-14)
   bf2  h(14-Girth)
   bf3  h(Height-72)

R>
```

Comment: Thanks Dirk. This is a start. I Can see the model, print it for a report or whatever. I guess I'm unclear how it addresses getting the model into some R variables so that I can use it. What I'm hoping to do is be able to use something like lapply to put it in the data frame with the original target and be able to look at things like correlation, etc. None the less thanks for the starting point.

Comment: I guess I should say that I can see what's in 'a' using names(a) and it appears that there are clues about the model looking at a["coefficients"] and the like. I understand that basic form of the earth model, so maybe the earth package leaves it to the user to build the model in R outside of the created earth element? I.e. - I have to read the structure, find the info, and then construct the model equation myself? I'd have to match the names of the selected inputs, use pmax, etc., and come up with the model explicitly? Thanks.